# Can't upload audio file to Cloudinary using Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, audio, cloudinary

I'm trying to add the audio file to Cloudinary storage. I got stuck when 
error show:

[CloudinaryException (Invalid resource type audio):

app/controllers/musics_controller.rb:23:in `create'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uueHe.png)

I've added configuration in my Music.rb file from another help in stack overflow:

```
has_attached_file :song, :storage => :cloudinary, path: 'muvent/musics/:filename', :cloudinary_resource_type => :audio
validates_with AttachmentSizeValidator, attributes: :song, less_than: 10.megabytes
validates_attachment_content_type :song, :content_type => [ 'application/octet-stream', 'audio/mpeg', 'audio/x-mpeg', 'audio/mp3', 'audio/x-mp3', 'audio/mpeg3', 'audio/x-mpeg3', 'audio/mpg', 'audio/x-mpg', 'audio/x-mpegaudio' ]
```

But, I still can't upload the file to Cloudinary. I also added permit for song column in my controller music_params which the error come. How can I fix this?

**Update**

I've fixed the error above. But why another error in logs server show `file -b --mime` in rails? Gemfile I use in here paperclip and paperclip-cloudinary.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure to use the right `resource_type` (a Cloudinary parameter) according to the file's type. The default resource type is `image`. Set it to `video` when uploading audio/video files or `raw` when uploading non-media files (such as doc,csv,css,js, etc).